# Semidirect product of group of order 44

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, group-presentation, semidirect-product

Problem statement: [Construct a nonabelian group of order 44](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197658/construct-a-nonabelian-group-of-order-44)

The answer claims that $Z_{11} \rtimes (Z_2 \times Z_2) \cong \langle a,b,c|a^{11}=1, b^2=c^2=1, bc=cb, b^{-1}ab = c^{-1}ac = a^{-1} \rangle$. But since only one of the element from $Z_2 \times Z_2$ is mapped to the inverse automorphism, shouldn't it be either $b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$ OR $c^{-1}ac=a^{-1}$?

Comment: There is a typo "$b^{-1}ab=?$ But..." You mean $$\mathbb Z_{11}\rtimes(\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2) = \langle a, b, c \mid a^{11}, b^2, c^2, [b,c], b^{-1}ab = c^{-1}ac = a^{-1} \rangle$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is just one way of naming the generators. Note that $(bc)^{-1}a(bc)=a$, so you can replace $c$ by $bc$ to get your desired presentation.